# Open any Linux Desktop in the browser

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, kde, gui, browser

Is there anyway to open default Ubuntu GUI ( or for that matter any Linux GUI like KDE, GNOME etc) right from the browser ?

All I can open is HTTPs port , We cannot open any other port (VNC or RDP) to the Unix Box and we need GUI to be accessible.

Comment: this makes no sense. A web browser interacts with web sites. Your Desktop is not a web site.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I believe OP wants something like a web shell, but for desktop use (KB/M)

Comment: You could tell `vnc` to listen on 443 - is that an option?

Comment: Check noVNC -> https://github.com/novnc/noVNC

Comment: [Apache Guacamole](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/preface.html) is another option.

Comment: this seems to be good option

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Weylus](https://github.com/H-M-H/Weylus). You can access your desktop using a web browser.

Comment: not clear how this helps

Comment: @sashank You can literally control your default Ubuntu GUI right from a web browser. What else do you want?

Comment: was looking for something like this , https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/preface.html, not sure that is what you are addressing

Comment: Have you tried ?